# How can I hide a scrollbar smoothly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, css-transitions

I need to hide the body scrollbar smoothly. I have tried overflow:hidden with transition but it does not work. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What you have tried so far ?? Show us your code.

Comment: Of course, overflow: hidden combined with transition. It hides, but not smoothly. It just disappears

Comment: @UkatJalal I edited the Fiddle link in my answer. I was clumsy enough to leave an old link on my clipboard and post that instead. If you click it now you will see the right result I was talking about.

Comment: @UkatJalal There are many possible answers to one question. You must explain it properly and show us what you have tried for better results. Answers with good explanation are never downvoted.

Comment: @RohitArora I think it is obvious. Nonetheless, I want to hide the body scrollbar on a click event, without distorting the page when it disappears.  I have tried overflow:hidden and transition: all .5s linear; on the html and body element. The scrollbar hides, but there is a distortion in the page. I need a solution that is smoother.

Comment: @RizkyFakkel Yes I saw that! Thank you! I am waiting for a less heavy  script solution. Otherwise I will vote your response as the best response!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no 'Short and simple' solution to do this. A scrollbar is not an element by itself, so you're going to end up having to make it yourself, and adding the `hover` or `click` effect on it or a different element. Fortunately there are other StackOverflow users that have done this before and shared this with us so that we can use this in the future and learn from it. The latter being the main reason of course, since that is what SO is mostly for.

[See this JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/PVZB8/139/)

This fiddle imitates the functionality of Facebook's scrollbar that **fades out** when you are not hovering over it anymore. All you need to do is make it work with a `click()` event instead of the `hover()` event.

Comment: **EDIT**:WRONG FIDDLE! changed it.

Comment: Before you go too far down this road be warned that this does not work on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late but you helped me out so I might as well try to help back haha.

The selector ::-webkit-scrollbar could be modified to have an opacity of 0 and you could apply overflow: hidden at the same time if you wrote it in jQuery or JS. Like add ::-webkit-scrollbar { opacity: 0; transition: all .25s;} whenever you're trying to.

Got the selector from this article.
https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Answer (score -2):

You can use below code to hide scroll bar

This will hide all scrollbars for textareas.

```
 textarea 
{ 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

You can also use the id or class of the textarea to make it only that one

```
textarea#txt 
{
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: The scrollbar hides! My problem is to hide it smoothly!

Comment: OP asked for a 'smooth' solution. This hides the bar instantly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on smootly means exactly what you want to achieve

Comment: It is pretty easy! When you set overflow: hidden on an event, say hover or click, scrollbar hides as if it was with display none. But this does not look good on the page. I want to hide it in a smooth way, without distorting the page at all.

Answer (score -2):

This will hide scroll smoothly as per your need

jQuery('html,body').stop().animate({scrollTop:900 },500,function(){});

Comment: I don't want to scroll smoothly, I want to hide the scrollbar smoothly! Rizky Fakkel seems to have an plausible answer.